# Can't connect to redis using Rails 7, Docker and hotwire-livereload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, redis

I'm trying to get gem hotwire-livereload working with my rails project. I'm trying to dockerise everything before I start to work. The hotwire-livereload gem uses redis to work.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:3.2.2

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y \
    nodejs

COPY Gemfile* ./
RUN gem install bundler && bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 3

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

And here is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    env_file:
      - .env

  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - '${DATABASE_PORT}:5432'
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data

volumes:
  db-data:
  redis-data:
```

When I try to run the docker, my app is starting, I can load the homepage, and then it's instantly crashing with the following error :
`Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL) (Redis::CannotConnectError)`

I tried differents docker-compose configurations but didn't manage to find one working